# Javascript scroll down by vh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I want to use this JavaScript command:

```
window.scrollBy(0,50);
```

It scrolls 50px down the page.

Is there a simple equivalent to scroll 50vh down the page? This doesn't work

```
window.scrollBy(0,50vh);
```

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366616/scroll-down-page-by-the-height-of-current-viewport%20here) but is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can divide the `window.innerHeight` by 2

```
window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight / 2);
```

Comment: Perfect, same as the other answer but quicker

Answer (score 5):

scrollBy accepts value in pixels only.

1vh = 1/100 viewport height. So you can calculate it manually.

```
window.scrollBy(0, valueInVh * window.innerHeight/100);
```

Comment: Good answer also, does the same as Michael Coker but more general so thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the JavaScript DOM APIs only give you pixel values. If you want "50vh" in pixels you can easily calculate it yourself:

```
// height in pixel
const height = window.innerHeight;
const vhPixels = height * 0.5

window.scrollBy(0, vhPixels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an invisible fixed element at the height you want the lower div to reach before changing the menu class. Position this fixed element using vh and for your scroll function test if the lower div has crossed the fixed element.

CSS:

```
#fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10vh;         /*or whatever height you want*/
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   

    var test = $('#fixed').offset().top;
    var lowerDivPosition = $('#lowerDiv').offset().top;

    if (lowerDivPosition >= test) { 
        $(".home").removeClass("open");
    };
});
```